# Difficulties with convincing when on any kind of project

Tags: project-management

Every so often I come across a person who won't heed to what I say to them especially in matters that are rather secondary. But sometimes these small matters later become counterproductive and I get very frustrated. And the reason I notice is that they think they are right but me otherwise.

For example: The other day a carpenter who was in our home doing some door fixing etc but wouldn't listen to the smaller details I asked him to do about how some things should be done around the house (thinking he knows more being a wood craftsman). So how to deal with these difficult persons. These type of situations happen to me a every so often which spoils my whole day.

The same situation also happened to me when I was preparing a thesis with a teacher who wouldn't listen sometimes about the smaller stuff which led to me getting failed the thesis.

But these sort of things doesn't happen with me when I am with some friend or family member though. But with other people I sometimes get very irritated with this.

I have also searched about and applied that politeness; straightforwardness etc. But sometimes people don't budge that leads to my headache.

So any good solutions to dealing with such persons?

Comment: Are you sure you are listening to them properly? It appears that you want things done differently than how they are though you may not be communicating that properly.

Comment: Hi Farooq, welcome to The Workplace! I'm not so sure this is a workplace problem as it stands. For instance, a carpenter in your home isn't an employee but an independent contractor, a technical expert in his or her field who you hired for that person's expertise. If you can focus on a specific workplace problem in an edit, we may be able to reopen. Hope this helps and thanks for participating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So any good solutions to dealing with such persons?

I'm not sure you are focusing on the most important part of the problem here.

You seem to be saying "If only I can get everyone to do everything I say, then everything will always be good."

It's possible that you are a simply poor communicator, and the real problem is that you are unconvincing. Perhaps a public speaking course would help.

But it seems more likely that the real problem is your reaction when others don't do everything you want them to do.

Real life means that sometimes we can convince others to do our bidding, and sometimes we cannot. The actions of others aren't always under our control. But the way we react to that circumstance is always under our control.

- Becoming mildly upset at a carpenter happens. Letting it ruin your
  entire day is about you, not the carpenter.
- Having a teacher who doesn't accept all of your suggestions is normal. Having that cause you to fail your thesis is not.

You might need to accept the fact that you need to work on your reaction to situations, rather than seeking to find a way to always be in complete control. The next time you can't convince someone to do things your way think "Ok. How am I reacting now? Does it really matter so much if I don't get my way here?"

Think about this, and if you still don't see a way clear, you might wish to seek counselling.

Comment: "It's possible that you are a poor communicator" From having seen his first post before he came back with this new and improved version, I have no doubt that his communication skills are poor on top of his other issues which you touched on. There are not too many things that build a sense of frustration for most of us more quickly than being at the receiving end of a poor attempt to communicate. And some of do lash out. For the OP, this is not a happy way to live.

Comment: On the other hand, I do - that first post was on hold as unclear and it was in far worse shape than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Managing people is tricky, especially if your relationship with them is very short-term. Some steps you might take:

- Be clear in your own mind about what you want. If you are making suggestions to the carpenter rather than making absolute statements about what you want, the carpenter might decide to rely on his own expertise rather than yours.
- Consider that the person you are trying to motivate does have expertise, so ask him his opinion, ask him why he is making the decisions he is making, talk to him about why you need the project done differently, then insist that it be done your way if you feel strongly. People are more likely to comply if their view has been considered.
- People don't often like to be told what to do, so soften your request. If you compliment the carpenter on all things he has done well,  and don't push for changes that you don't really need, then he may be more compromising on the details you ask for.
- If you are in charge, then there must be consequences for someone not following your instruction. In the case of the teacher, perhaps you were not in charge, which makes it more difficult. But if I ask a carpenter to do something a particular way and he chooses not to, I will expect him to redo it before I pay him.
- Work on your assertiveness. When your grade is at stake, you must stand up for yourself and refuse to do something that is against your best interest. It is possible to be assertive without being confrontational. Stand firm, keep repeating your request if you are challenged, and keep your emotions steady and friendly: "I know you disagree, but this is really the way I want it done as it is my [cabinetry][grade][project] that is at stake. Thank you for understanding."

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed reply. Really appreciate it.